# Storage area of DataTable of ADO.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, ado.net

In ADO.Net C#, DataTable is used to store information in table format when query is executed through SqlDataAdapter object.

So, I want to know how and where this DataTable store information internally/logically in memory.

Comment: The `DataTable` has `Columns` and `Rows` properties, is that what you want to know? In general it's just an object that is stored in memory like any other object.

Comment: Ya you are absolutely right.
But DataTable logically manage a multidimensional array to holds records in  rows and columns format.
So i want to know where this array is store/manage

Answer (score 0):

it will be stored in client network buffer.

I read it some where earlier but doesn't remember reference details exactly.